# import * as Location from 'expo-location'; error

Tags: react-native, expo

I think

```
> import * as Location from 'expo-location';
```

this code is problem.
Is any way to solve this?

the error message is

> Unable to resolve module ./ExpoLocation from
> C:\Users\USER\location\node_modules\expo-location\build\Location.js:
>
> None of these files exist:   *
> node_modules\expo-location\build\ExpoLocation(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
>
> - node_modules\expo-location\build\ExpoLocation\index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
>   1 | import { PermissionStatus, createPermissionHook, Platform, } from
>   'expo-modules-core';
>
> > 2 | import ExpoLocation from './ExpoLocation';
> > |                           ^   3 | import { LocationAccuracy, LocationActivityType, LocationGeofencingEventType,
> > LocationGeofencingRegionState, } from './Location.types';   4 | import
> > { LocationEventEmitter } from './LocationEventEmitter';   5 | import {
> > setGoogleApiKey, googleGeocodeAsync, googleReverseGeocodeAsync, } from
> > './LocationGoogleGeocoding';
>
> ABI45_0_0facebook::ABI45_0_0React::JSIExecutor::defaultTimeoutInvoker(std::__1::function<void
> ()> const&, std::__1::function<std::__1::basic_string<char,
> std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > ()>)
> ABI45_0_0facebook::ABI45_0_0React::JSIExecutor::defaultTimeoutInvoker(std::__1::function<void
> ()> const&, std::__1::function<std::__1::basic_string<char,
> std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > ()>)
> 355ACCF4-3917-3730-BC55-EF7003887ABE
> 355ACCF4-3917-3730-BC55-EF7003887ABE
> 355ACCF4-3917-3730-BC55-EF7003887ABE
> _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF 5198FB57-5645-3B34-A49F-F32B52256CF3 5198FB57-5645-3B34-A49F-F32B52256CF3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
> GSEventRunModal 3ED35565-456D-33CB-B554-6C567FA81585 UIApplicationMain
> Expo Go start

Comment: Will you please provide your package.json?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should reinstall the expo location module. If it is not properly installed you can either use `npm install expo-location expo-task-manager` or `yarn add expo-location expo-task-manager` depending upon the package manager you are using and I hope it will run.

Answer (score -1):

*It works for me.*

**I just installed it.**

```
yarn add expo-location
```

`